# Highcharts gauge needles

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this `gauge chart` - http://jsfiddle.net/xfV5k/44/

Here I am not able to see third needle of the gauge. Also is there a way to have all the needles start point same ?

What I have missed here?
Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing series.data only for two needles. Add data for third one as well. And for making start point same, just change the yAxis value to 0 or whatever is suitable for you.

```
series: [{
        data: [{y:-6, color: 'red'}],
        yAxis: 0,
                dial: {
                    backgroundColor : 'red'
                }

    },{
        data: [{y:-4, color: 'yellow'}],
        yAxis: 0,
                dial: {
                    backgroundColor : 'yellow'
                }

    },{
        data: [{y:-2}],
        yAxis: 0,
                dial: {
                    backgroundColor : 'green'
                }

}]

});
```

Comment: I have posted the link for wrong fiddle. Pls check this - [gauge](http://jsfiddle.net/xfV5k/44/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Is this the way you want

For the third needle I added

```
{
            data: [{y:-1,color:'blue'}],
            yAxis: 0,
                    dial: {
                        backgroundColor : 'blue'
                    }

    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kapilgopinath/xfV5k/42/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your last needle data is out of range. Try to change i.e to 250 and you will notice that needle exists.